# Typography basline & size changing when web site on live server

Tags: css, apache, xhtml, web

I have a rather bizarre situation, and it's not the first time I this has happened. I have a web site I am developing (a Wordpress template, but that's irrelevant in this context).

I have noticed a distinct shift in the baseline grid of the typography, as well as the SIZE of the type used in my web site template.

I have attached two screenshots. The first one is a preview of the web site on my local testing server (windows XP SP3 Apache 2.2.8) and the second is of the live site, hosted on a Debian Linux machine running Apache web server.

Can anyone throw some ideas around as to why this is happening? Is it a doctype issue? The doctype declared in the latest Wordpress header file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Screenshots:

[image: Offline Preview]
[image: Online Preview]

Many thanks to all who contribute.

Comment: Needs more info. In what browsers are you seeing this?

Comment: +1 needs more info. How did you add those lines? If those are added to the screenshot afterwards (as opposed to rendered on the baseline in the browser), I would say that the only problem you are seeing is the change in font size.

Comment: @all, CSS, XHTML & CSS is EXACTLY the same. Lines were added afterwards yes, but on the exact same screenshot in both browsers, there is a definite shift and size change. Browser: Firefox 3.6.13, XP SP3 Apache 2.2.8 (if relevant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the screenshots, my first guess would be a "Zoom" setting that is stuck at 125% or a similar enlarged setting for the second screen shot.

If that's not it, we need more info.

- What browser(s) are you seeing this in
- Is this on the same machine
- Do all style sheets get loaded
- Calls for seeing some code will follow soon :)

Comment: Most certainly not a zoom issue no. I am literally switching between two tabs in Firefox, one live, one local. Exact same markup, line for line. I cannot post all code here (css file is huge) but the site is at http://www.webfactory.co.za/top100preview/blog/

Comment: Yes it is one the same machine. All style sheets are loaded (there is even a global css reset). There is also an increase in the line height!

Comment: @webfac you have confirmed that there is the normal zoom level set in the "view" menu on both sites? (Or press `Ctrl`+ `0`)

Comment: You would NOT believe it. It seems that for ALL (NOT just this) sites loading on domain localhost (all my dev sites) the zoom was SMALLER! After resetting all zooms they are both now perfect. Cannot believe this, how embarrassing! Apologies I wasted every ones time. At least there will be no further issues!

Comment: @webfac no problem. It happens to everyone at least once :)

Answer (score 0):

You should verify that the HTML, CSS and JS is identical in both test cases.